# Json data truncated on cell network ok on wifi

Tags: ios, json, swift

Using the following code to retrieve data via a php file from MySQL works great on wifi but not on mobile it seems to truncate the response. Any help to approach debugging this would be much appreciated. See print outputs pasted into code below for cell v wifi

```
func get(){

let urlcustom = "http://myserver.com/swiftly/phpget.php?team_id=\(theteam)"
let url = URL(string: urlcustom)
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
values = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSArray
tableView.reloadData()
print("get ran \(data)")
// mobile phone cell connection - FAIL
// get ran Optional(<5b5d>)

// Wifi Connection
//get ran Optional(<5b7b2269 64223a22 31222c22 7465616d 5f696422 3a223122 2c226e61 6d65223a 22457669 65205072 6f637465 72222c22 646f6222 3a223230 30362d30 312d3033 222c2270 686f746f 223a2222 7d5d>)


}
```

Comment: Use a proxy tool to monitor the messages sent and received, is the server timing the connection out?

Comment: Check that content type header is correctly set to application/json. Its probably caused by some router or proxy.

Comment: How do I check the content type header ?

Comment: The retrieved data through cell network is "[]", it is very likely the server returned an empty array. Are you testing by connecting to the same server with exactly the same URL for both networks?

Comment: Yes. Same app. Switching wifi on and off on iPhone to test while plugged into Xcode to get print data

Comment: You are right if I print values I get empty data on cell network.

Comment: Isn't there any possibility that your local wifi network has an internal DNS server which leads the access to your local testing server? For me, the results shown seem to be sent form two different servers.

Comment: Not connecting to a local server. Both connections are to external server.

Comment: Strange, but we need to face the confirmed fact. You know sort of network failure is very unlikely to produce an empty JSON array. So, as for now, I have no clue. Waiting for any updates.

Comment: I have made the following discovery... it seems that when on mobile connection the data is cached in fact, I was gettng nothing as I had cleared the database and then made changes.. however after testing today and making changes database side when on 3g connection the data does not update... so I either need to force data to be updated in app (if thats where the cache is) or its a phone network caching issues. which I think I could make my PHP / server be more forceful at non caching

Comment: I think I need to create a URL session  though I dont know how yet - let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default()
        config.urlCache = nil
        let mySession = URLSession(configuration: config)   - cant format comment either

Comment: I have started to add this to all my headers :  <?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

 $host='localhost';

Comment: Ok I had to add that to each php and moved everything to a new location on server and all seems good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to all my files :

```
<?php 
header("Content-Type: application/json"); header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false); 
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
$host='localhost';
```

All works now.